# shorten every line in a text file by exactly 59 charaters then add a new shorter string in their place

Tags: string, batch-file, replace

For something so simple that can easily be done with find replace in notepad, I can't see why it is so hard to do in a command line as it is just one step in the entire procedure that I would like to get down to a single run.  The output from the  first part lists the local path to all the websites in the webserver as the each local path c:/  etc.  every site has the same 59 characters  before the part that matters.

To make this a usable link, I need to then add a different string in the same position as the old one with the correct http://. etc.  to the balance of the line to make it a working hyperlink.
The final step needs to convert any single "\’s" that are left to a "/".  Normally there is only one

All of this can be done in notepad++ using find and replace but it takes 3 runs to achieve the end result  the original text file is nothing special, no skipped lines, everyone is identical in layout.

The same 59 characters need to be chopped off (it could even be by Number and not by comparing the text, just shorten by 59 characters if that is easier.  The replacement text string is always exactly the same that just gets appended to each line.  And for the final touch of replacing every \ with a / to make it fully web-compatible there is only one occurrence on each line.

I have seen many find and replace batch-files that seem to be overkill for such a simple task.
Take each line, count fifty nine characters forward, chop off the 59 and add in the replacement text in its place.

Then change the only  backslash in the line to a forward slash and it’s done

Does anyone know a simpler easier way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Just change `http://www.domain.com/` to what you need to prefix the lines with.

```
type "file.txt" | repl "\\" "/" | repl "^.{59}" "http://www.domain.com/" >"newfile.txt"
```

The two \\ are intentional as it is a regular expression.

Comment: I downloaded repl.bat into folder with file.txt.  Opened command prompt in the folder typed in statement.  But result was only a blank newfile.txt.  I read through the repl.bat info and I am sure I can find other uses for a script which is that versatile.  Thanks very much for the reply and link.  The script presented by Magoo worked for this specific need.  But your contribution will certainly be of use on later projects due to the wide range of capabilities.  Maybe all the "\", "/" and ":" in the original file are causing a problem?  Repl.bat will definitely go in my script toolbox.  Thanks!

Comment: Try it again, and make sure that the lines are over 59 characters long. (copy/paste it to eliminate any typos). It doesn't need to have any \ or / in it to work in this case.  I'm glad that you see the usefulness of the script, and as a hybrid jscript it is both very fast on large files and very robust. The SO user dbenham wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (Q21495128.txt) DO (
  SET "line=%%a"
  CALL SET "line=%%line:\=/%%"
  CALL SET "line=replacement text%%line:~59%%"
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%x IN ('set line') DO ECHO %%y
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

where `Q21495128.txt` was my test source file worked for me.

Comment: Many Grateful Thanks!  That worked like a charm!  I tried to vote you up but cannot due to lack of "reputation"  I guess since I signed in as a guest.  changing the input file name, and the replaced data resulted in a perfect output file.  This definitely WAS the solution and will save me a lot of time using notepad++.  It has the added advantage of being generic enough to add it to the previous script I had.  Now I can do a one click start to finish. :)